# How do I make the input value get verified?

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, frontend

I'm trying to code a basic first degree equation calculator , but my input value is not getting verified can someone help , I appreciate your attention

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="scriptfoda.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
var eq = Document.getElementById('cu');
var someigual = eq.slipt("=");
function butao() {
  if (eq.value.includes("x") && eq.value.includes("=") == false){
      eq.innerHTML = "PLEASE PUT X AND = IN THE EQUATION";
  }
}
</script>
</head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" name="button" onclick="butao()">top</button>
    <input type="text" size="99" id="cu" placeholder="coloque uma equaçao de 1 grau com 1 icognita">
    <p id="error"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I assume `var someigual = eq.slipt("=");` should be **split** .. so `var someigual = eq.split("=");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things that were wrong about your code, so ill provide some feedback on that. When your script initialises, you are trying to get the initial value of `eq`, but it only ever gets that value the one time, rather than on each click. This should be moved inside `butao`

Your `if` statement isn't doing what you think it is, it is checking if it includes `x` and if it doesnt include `=`. What i assume you want, is to check that `eq.value` **does** include both `x` and `=`, so you want to make sure that neither are missing, hence checking if either of them are false, and then putting the error.

You want `document.getElementById()` not `Document.getElementById()`

You (most likely) wanted to alter the value of the input, rather than the `innerhtml`

`slipt` is not a function, and i assume you mispelt `split`

```js
function butao() {
  
  var eq = document.getElementById('cu');
  var someigual = eq.value.split("=");

  if (!eq.value.includes("x") || !eq.value.includes("=")) {
    eq.value = "PLEASE PUT X AND = IN THE EQUATION";
  } 
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  <button type="button" name="button" onclick="butao()">top</button>
  <input type="text" size="99" id="cu" placeholder="coloque uma equaçao de 1 grau com 1 icognita">
  <p id="error"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Bold assumption I know, but they probably wanted that `error` message in the `error` container, so `var error = document.getElementById(error);` and `error.innerHTML= "PLEASE PUT X AND = IN THE EQUATION";`

Comment: yes, i was going to do that, but didn't want to alter the code in ways by making those assumptions. As they say, 'better to be safe than sorry' (though be it pretty low risk...)